# Navigate to router after resolving a value

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a buy now button for my cart and if I click it, it will push the item details on the back end, return something and then automatically navigate to cart.

Please take a look at my current implementation.

```
addItem(){
    if(!localStorage.getItem('currentUserToken')){
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    } else {
        this.product[0].userId = localStorage.getItem('currentUserId');
        console.log(this.product);
        this._productsService.addToCart(this.product)
            .subscribe((updated) => console.log(updated),
            err => console.log(err));
    }
}

buyNow(){
    this.addItem();
    this._router.navigate(['/cart']);
}
```

The problem here is that the navigation takes place faster than the backend pushing to the database and back to angular2. How can I wait for the resolve to finish then navigate?

Answer (score 1):

You have to redirect after you get response from your backend as below :

```
addItem(){
    if(!localStorage.getItem('currentUserToken')){
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    } else {
        this.product[0].userId = localStorage.getItem('currentUserId');
        console.log(this.product);
        this._productsService.addToCart(this.product)
            .subscribe((updated) => {
              console.log(updated);
              this._router.navigate(['/cart']);
            },
            err => console.log(err));
    }
}

buyNow(){
  this.addItem();    
}
```

Comment: addItem() is used for my add to cart button without going to cart. Buy now button is used to add the item to cart and redirect to cart page. Sorry for misunderstanding my logic.